# brew services: where to edit configuration?

Tags: mysql, plist, homebrew

Brew services has installed this plist file for mysql.

```
~ $ brew services list
Name    Status  User      Plist
mysql56 started mh /Users/mh/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist
```

Is this file safe to edit (i.e. will brew ever overwrite changes made here)?  Is there another method I should use to modify the file?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

All `.plist` files that come with Formulas can be found in Cellar dir. For instance `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` is in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.14`. You can modify it and  `brew services` will use it.

Alternatively you can modify `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` and make it immutable with `sudo chflags uchg /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`. This won't allow `brew` to rewrite or modify `.plist` file.

Comment: Your are not going to be able to start the brew services again by making the .plist immutable. When starting I get: `Error: Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - /Users/ci/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist`. Brew services requires the plist file to be writable.

Comment: I just tried this out by putting different values on the `LaunchDaemons` plist file, and I can confirm that the correct file to edit is the `Cellar` version. The `LaunchDaemons` version will get copied to / overwritten by the `Cellar` version on a `brew services start`.

Comment: As an additional note, it's easier to go to `/usr/local/opt/` instead of `/usr/local/Cellar` because `/opt` just symlinks to the appropriate match in `/Cellar`. This guide explains how `brew services` interact with LaunchAgents: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew

Comment: For quickly, find the .plist file by running command:
`locate homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist`
the file path will be displayed in output.

Comment: After [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/pull/332/files#diff-642a732918ee1aeca833e8380816320040a75eb97db5c2743e56e5ad71fc3626L38), you should use `brew edit <service>` to update the `plist` method in the formula. The plist file is generated every time you restart a service.

Comment: Jenkins will not start if you make the file unmodifiable. I found my origin at /opt/homebrew with Ventura ARM. How I hate macOS.

Answer (score 15):

1. Copy `/Users/mh/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist` somewhere
2. make changes to copy of plist
3. run `brew services start mysql56 {path to modified copy of plist file}`

Update 2022 - for newer versions:

3. run `brew services start mysql56 --file=path to modified copy of plist file`

Comment: With newer version, note that file as last argument is deprecated! Use `--file=` to specify a plist file instead.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer:

Edit the configuration in `usr/local/Cellar/` + name of the Formula / + `.plist` file

**NOT** in the file listed next to the daemon in `brew services` listing

---

Long answer:

When you install a Formula, its `plist` file lands in `usr/local/Cellar`, in a dir named after the formula.

When you spawn a daemon with `brew services start`, this file is then **copied** to the running user's `Library/LaunchAgents/`, e.g.:

for root, it's `Library/LaunchAgents/`

for a normal user - `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

This is important, there is no point in changing this file, it's just a copy that will be overwritten next time you run the service **as this user**.

However, you can examine this file to see what configuration was used for this particular instance of the service.

Answer (score 6):

I (unfortunately) don't know which file you *can* edit, but I can confirm that editing anything in the `Library/LaunchAgents` directory will be overwritten by `brew services` on the next start, so editing it directly isn't going to help.

Comment: Confirmed. And this is a pain in the ass.

Comment: However you can stop that from happening by using `chflags uchg <file>` (and later `chflags nouchg <file>`).

Comment: You are able to edit both, but you *should* edit the `Cellar` version of the file. @pnomolos answer is correct, `brew services start` overwrites the `LaunchAgents` version of the file with whatever was in `Cellar` .

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package with Homebrew formula a .plist file is placed in the package folder (usually /usr/local/Cellar/... folder).

In OSX this file is copyed/deleted to/from the

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/

folder every time tou start/stop the service with Homebrew:

```
brew services start <the-app>
brew services stop  <the-app>
```

Better than 'blocking' this file is acting over the file in your package folder...

This example is for OSX/Mojave & MariaDB:

Suppose you want to change the default data folder and the TCP port from 3306 to 3308.

Edit the:

> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.6_1/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist

Locate this section in the XML and make you desired changes (choose you desired folder):

```
...
<string>/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
<string>--datadir=/DAT/mariadb</string>     
<string>--port=3308</string> 
...
```

Then just stop and restart the service with Homebrew, et voilá. You can use `netstat` to confirm:

```
netstat | grep 3308
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in year 2024. Now the paths are bit different, and the behavior is different too.

You can find the config file with command:
`brew services list`
yet, `brew services start` will generate / overwrite the config file.
The original template file path somehow changes over time.
Right now for my case it is:
`/opt/homebrew/opt/...`

Comment: run ```brew --prefix mysql ```.  Which will give you the directory.  Then edit homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist in that directory.   Then restart the service