# Change mysql (homebrew) data dir

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I would like to store my mysql databases on an external hard drive. Right now, the data is located at the default data dir `/usr/local/var/mysql/` since I have installed mysql via homebrew.

To change the data dir, I have modified the datadir entry in the following file: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--datadir=/Volumes/EXTHD/mysql</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Unfortunately that did not change anything. I have also created the file `/etc/my.cnf` with that datadir entry. No success.

What else do I have to change to move the data to an external hard drive?

Comment: With a homebrew install , you will probably find the config at `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` .  Edit that, then restart mysqld

Comment: This file does not exist.

Comment: An installation without homebrew and a manual creation of the file `/etc/my.cnf` with just the entry `datadir=/myPath/` below `[mysqld]` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify it in `/usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

(You might also need the check, whether this is the right location by `brew --prefix mysql`)

See: [brew services: where to edit configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089384/brew-services-where-to-edit-configuration)