# Where are homebrew services logs

Tags: service, homebrew

When I run `brew services start mosquitto`, The service does not start. When I use `brew services list`, the services has a yellow `started` status. I want to know why this service start failed, how?

Answer (score 63):

The usual logs end up in `/usr/local/var/log/`.

Comment: or `/opt/homebrew/var/log` on ARM like m1.

Comment: I don't have either of these directories (M1 Monterey)

Comment: I haven't tried on other systems, but you should be able to use `brew --prefix` to find the folder where `var/log` resides

Comment: There are no Homebrew logs on my MacBook Pro M2 (arm64), after a failed attempt to run `dnscrypt-proxy`. This invocation finds nothing: `sudo find /opt/homebrew/ /usr/local/ -name 'log'`. Where are the logs supposed to be?

Answer (score 8):

When you see "started" in yellow for a brew service means that the status of the service is "unknown", the started text is printed for retro compatibility.

In your case I suggest to add some log output to your .plist associated file, to edit the correct plist file check the output of "brew services list" command on the mosquitto line you will have the name of the correspondent .plist file, edit that file and add two entries, I print the plist file that I use for my apache installation, please use this file as a guide. check the lines for StandardOutPath and StandardErrorPath and create something similar for your specific case.

After saving the file try to run again the service but this time check the logs associated.
In my experience when you see a yellow started, this means that you have some permissions problem, you can try to save the data associated and reinstall the brew formulae as a second option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.httpd</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>FOREGROUND</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/hombebrew/httpd/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/hombebrew/httpd/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.stderr.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I made this change, but `brew services restart <service>` is silently rewriting my .plist file

Comment: see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38718808/2016805)

Answer (score 4):

This answer came from a comment from @AlexV but it deserves its own answer in my opinion.

The logs can be found on:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/log
```

on M1, M2 or M3 ARM chips.

Answer (score 3):

On mine I found them here:

```
/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log
```

Your mileage may of course vary :-)

Answer (score 2):

- /opt/homebrew/var/log/prometheus.log
- /opt/homebrew/var/log/prometheus.err.log